# How to run shell script in Jmeter - Groovy

Tags: groovy, jmeter, sh

I am trying to run script on remote computer using groovy in jsr223 sampler in jmeter.
The problem that I do not get any response if the script success or not, or even if it success login or any indication.
to be sure that this behavior occurred all the time, I created imaginary script and run it, and still nothing in response.
here is the script

```
"c:/Program Files/PuTTY/plink.exe jenkins@174.257.244.157 -pw test!67  sudo /opt/mew/run_me.sh".execute().text
```

the server and the password are fake.  but in the real script they are real.
can someone please advise?
the plink.exe destination is correct, if I use '\' instead of '/' it failed so I just change the directions.

but their is no way to know what happened, I want to do it via code and with no jmeter sampler that I faced difficulties.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I can think of 3 reasons for not returning anything

1. You're being asked to add your `174.257.244.157` to the [SSH Known Hosts](https://www.ssh.com/ssh/host-key#sec-Known-Host-Keys)
2. You're being asked for the password of your `jenkins` user for [sudo](https://www.lifewire.com/what-to-know-sudo-command-3576779) command execution, if this is the case add the `jenkins` user to `sudo` group and configure it to be able to [run commands without prompting for password](https://www.tecmint.com/run-sudo-command-without-password-linux/)
3. Your `/opt/mew/run_me.sh` does/outputs nothing, try adding something like `echo "Starting..."` to the beginning to have at least some output. Or substitute it with some command which is guaranteed to work like `ls` or `whoami` or `date`

In order to get more idea of what's going on you can amend your Groovy script to use [ProcessBuilder](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html) class like:

```
new ProcessBuilder("c:/Program Files/PuTTY/plink.exe jenkins@174.257.244.157 -pw test!67  sudo /opt/mew/run_me.sh").inheritIO().start().text
```

More information: [Apache Groovy - Why and How You Should Use It](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black)

Comment: I will give it a try, I managed finally to run it via the OS Sampler and it gives response from that location. So if it is working from the OS Sampler it must to work from the JSR223 as well in the same way, am I correct?